# Converting between decimal and hexadecimal in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have a byte value of 0x12 (decimal 18). I need to convert this into decimal 12. Here's how I do it:

```
byte hex = 0x12;
byte dec = Byte.parseByte(String.format("%2x", hex));
System.out.println(dec); // 12
```

Is there a better way of doing this (for example without using strings and parsing)?

Comment: What should happen to `byte hex = 0xf2;`? Is this BCD format?

Comment: It will throw a NumberFormatException, but that's fine, the data I am working with will not have such values and there will be an exception handler to handle incorrect data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte dec = (byte)(hex / 16 * 10 + hex % 16);
```

Note that it assumes that the original input is a valid [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) encoding.

Comment: Basically you have the right idea, but to get the exact result needed the input needs to be an int (int hex = 0x99; byte dec = (byte) (hex / 16 * 10 + hex % 16); System.out.println(dec); // prints 99)

Comment: note that if you use a logical bit shift instead of division, you avoid the signedness issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterpret a Binary coded decimal and convert to binary, you can convert to a hexadecimal string and interpret as a decimal string. Your method is a perfectly valid way to do it (be careful, though, that `byte`s are signed in Java.

Read up on Binary Coded Decimals here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

If you want to avoid string conversion, you could separate each nibble (four bytes) and multiply by the correct value:

```
byte hex = 0x12;

if( hex&15 > 9 || hex>>>4 > 9)
 throw new NumberFormatException(); //check for valid input

byte dec = (byte)((hex & 15) + 10*(hex>>>4 & 15));
```

If your input is wider than a byte, this method gets out of hand easily as you need to handle each nibble separately.

Comment: Intersting approach. However, this does not work for `byte hex = (byte) 0x99`. Apologies, it actually does if the input is an integer (`int hex = 0x99`)

Comment: @Sevas Why not, apart from casting issues (which I've fixed)?

Comment: It returns -61 (decimal) if the input is a byte with the value of 0x99

Comment: @Sevas used the wrong bit shift operator (signed bit shift when I intended unsigned bit shift), sorry. Fixed.

Comment: I'm afraid `byte hex = (byte) 0x99; byte dec = (byte) ((hex & 15) + 10 * (hex >>> 4)); System.out.println(dec);` still prints out -61

Comment: WTH? When I perform `hex >>> 4`, java 1) casts `hex` to `int` (signed) and then 2) performs 32-bit unsigned right shift. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hex to Decimal - Integer.parseInt(str,16)

Decimal to Hex - Integer.toHexString(195012)